# How do I watch youtube videos?

Tags: flash, adobe

The new adobe flash player does not work (at least for me) as of 2014. Is there a different way?
ubuntu 12.04, 
firefox

Comment: Does the one built into chrome work?

Comment: Do you have the 11.2 r202 version ? (check it on firefox in "plugins")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those who want to watch YouTube in Ubuntu - Install [YouTube All HTML5](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-all-html5) and forget Flash forever. The downside: Videos will not be available in 240p and 1080p but in other formats you can watch.